# Regular user can not access NFS4 mounts (permission denied)

Tags: file-permissions, nfs4

I have nfsserver and nfsclient machines.

On nfsserver:

```
# cat /etc/exports
/export        gss/krb5p(rw,sync,fsid=0,no_subtree_check,crossmnt)
/export/home   gss/krb5p(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

On nfsclient it mounts OK:

```
# mount -vvv -t nfs4 -o sec=krb5p nfsserver:/home /homex
mount: fstab path: "/etc/fstab"
mount: mtab path:  "/etc/mtab"
mount: lock path:  "/etc/mtab~"
mount: temp path:  "/etc/mtab.tmp"
mount: UID:        0
mount: eUID:       0
mount: spec:  "nfsserver:/home"
mount: node:  "/homex"
mount: types: "nfs4"
mount: opts:  "sec=krb5p"
mount: external mount: argv[0] = "/sbin/mount.nfs4"
mount: external mount: argv[1] = "nfsserver:/home"
mount: external mount: argv[2] = "/homex"
mount: external mount: argv[3] = "-v"
mount: external mount: argv[4] = "-o"
mount: external mount: argv[5] = "rw,sec=krb5p"
mount.nfs4: timeout set for Tue Apr 30 13:03:13 2013
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5p,addr=10.10.10.100,clientaddr=10.10.10.101'
nfsserver:/home on /homex type nfs4 (rw,sec=krb5p)
```

But I can only access this directory as root. Regular user gets:

```
$ ls /homex
ls: cannot access /homex: Permission denied

$ df /homex
df: `/homex': Permission denied
df: no file systems processed
```

I turned on all NFS debugging on both sides (nfsserver,nfsclient) with `rpcdebug` but the only thing I see on the nfsclient during regular user trying to access mounted directory is:

```
Apr 30 12:51:19 nfsclient kernel: [ 5896.339330] NFS: permission(0:13/917551), mask=0x24, res=-13

Apr 30 12:51:32 nfsclient kernel: [ 5909.182185] NFS: revalidating (0:13/917551)
Apr 30 12:51:32 nfsclient kernel: [ 5909.189372] nfs_revalidate_inode: (0:13/917551) getattr failed, error=-13
```

There is nothing on nfsserver side then (even no network traffic when sniffing with tcpdump).

File permissions seems to be OK:

```
# ls -ld /homex
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr  5 18:15 /homex

# ls -l /homex
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 6 mike mike 4096 Apr 29 13:48 mike


# df /homex
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
nfsserver:/home
                  20640384   1390208  18201600   8% /homex
```

User mike has the same UID on both machines.

Answer (score 2):

Kerberized NFS (any `gss`) requires Kerberos tickets. You'll have to use the much less secure `sys` security level if you want uses to be able to access NFS without tickets.

It would be better to have users acquire tickets when they log in. Ether by using `sssd` or `pam_krb5` as part of you `pam` auth stack, or by credential delegation for `ssh` (i.e. `GSSAPIAuthentication yes` and `GSSAPIDelegateCredentials`).

Answer (score 0):

So the user can access NFS mount after acquiring Kerberos ticket with `kinit`.

[But how to let the user access NFS mount without a ticket?](https://serverfault.com/questions/503846/nfs-kerberos-can-regular-users-access-mounted-directory-without-kerberos-tick)