# NFS + Kerberos: can regular users access mounted directory without Kerberos ticket (kinit)?

Tags: kerberos, nfs4

I had this [issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/503830/regular-user-can-not-access-nfs4-mounts-permission-denied), which turned out to be caused by lack of Kerberos ticket.
So the user can access NFS mount after doing **kinit**.

Is there any way to let users access NFS mounts without a need to acquire Kerberos ticket?

Update: Please note that the NFS export is already mounted on nfsclient machine via /etc/fstab:

```
nfsserver:/home /homex  nfs4    sec=krb5p 0 0
```

Maybe I misunderstood a concept of NFS+Kerberos but I only wanted nfsclient to authenticate to nfsserver (and vice versa) by Kerberos during the mount and after that I would like all local nfsclient users to access the mount locally as it was a local filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

The users need to be authenticated to the domain controller via Kerberos service. If they are using a Windows workstation in the same domain, you need to propagate the TGT from the Windows workstation to the Linux one.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not use any Windows, though.